# Need algorithm suggestions for flight routings

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm in the early stages of thinking through a wild trip that involves visiting every commercial airport in India. A little research shows that the national carrier - Air India, has a special ticket called the [Silver Pass](http://www.airindia.in/SBCMS/Webpages/silver-platinum-pass-002.aspx?MID=23) that allows unlimited travel on their domestic network for 15 days. I would like to use this as my weapon of choice!

[See this for a map of all the airports served by Air India](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=IXA,%20AGX,%20AMD,%20AJL,%20IXD,%20ATQ,%20IXU,%20IXB,%20BLR,%20BHO,%20BBI,%20IXC,%20MAA,%20CJB,%20DED,%20DEL,%20DIB,%20DMU,%20GAY,%20GOI,%20GWL,%20GAU,%20HYD,%20IMF,%20IDR,%20JLR,%20JAI,%20IXJ,%20JGA,%20JDH,%20JRH,%20KNU,%20HJR,%20COK,%20CCU,%20CCJ,%20KUU,%20IXL,%20IXI,%20LKO,%20IXM,%20IXE,%20BOM,%20NAG,%20IXP,%20PAT,%20IXZ,%20PNQ,%20RPR,%20RAJ,%20IXR,%20SHL,%20IXS,%20SXR,%20STV,%20TEZ,%20TRV,%20TRZ,%20TIR,%20UDR,%20BDQ,%20VNS,%20VGA,%20VTZ&PC=#ff0000&RC=#000080&DU=mi)

I have the following information available with me in Excel:

- All of the domestic flight routes (departure airports and arrival airports in IATA codes)
- Duration for every flight route
- Weekly frequency for every flight (not all flights run on all days of the week, for example)

Given this information, how do I figure out what is the maximum number of airports that I can hit in 15 days using the Silver Pass ticket? Looking online shows that this is either a traveling salesman problem or a graph traversal problem. What would you guys recommend that I look at to solve this.

Some background on myself - I'm just beginning to learn Python and would like to figure out a way to solve this problem using that. Given that, what are the python-based algorithms/libraries that I should be looking at that will help me structure an approach to solving this?

Comment: As an intellectual exercise? Or are you seriously considering doing this?

Comment: Why would you spend 15 days stressing in terminals?

Comment: @MattH, definitely considering this. Need to figure out routing and then cost. Apparently, over and above the cost of the Silver Pass there's also a per-flight route cost that will vary based on the distance travelled. However, I'm not considering that at this stage for figuring out a routing as I don't want to complicate this further

Comment: @nightcracker I'm a [FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com) member - does that explain it? :)

Comment: [Longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). You want to visit as many different nodes as possible, so from each vertex find the longest path.

Comment: The travelling salesman problem _is_ a graph traversal problem. :)

Comment: Do you have a fixed start point, or can you start from anywhere on the network?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is closely related to the [Hamiltonian Path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) and [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which are [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

Given an instance of Hamiltonian Path Problem - build a flight data:

1. Each vertex is an airport
2. Each edge is a flight
3. All flights leave at the same time and takes the same time.(*)

(*)The flight duration and departure time [which are common for all] should be calculated so you will be able to visit all terminals only if you visit each terminal only once. It can be easily done in polynomial time. Assume we have a fixed time of `k` hours for the ticket, we construct the flight table such that each flight takes exactly `k/(n-1)` hours, and there is a flight every `k/(n-1)` hours as well<sup>1</sup> [remember all flights are at the same time].

It is easy to see that if and only if the graph has a hamiltonian path, you can use the ticket to visit al airports, since if we visit a certain airport twice in the path, we need at least `n` flights and the total time will be at least `(k/(n-1)) * n > k`, and we failed the time limit. [other way around is similar].

Thus your problem [for general case] is NP-Hard, and **there is no known polynomial solution for it.**

---

1: We assume it takes no time to pass between flights, this can be easily fixed by simply decreasing flight length by the time it takes to "jump" between two flights.

Comment: I don't think he has the limitation of visiting every airport exactly once.

Comment: @Mig: The limitation is constructed in the reduction, we "build" the problem such that if you visit a certain airport twice - you cannot visit all the airports in time. Let's assume we have a total time of `k`, and we have `n` airports [vertices], then in the instance we built, each flight takes `k/(n-1)` time. If we visit a certain airport twice, we need to take at least `n` flights, and we spent toal of `(k/(n-1))*n > k` time, and we failed.

Comment: @Mig: I editted the answer to clarify what we just discussed on comments.

Comment: Thanks @amit - as my math is quite limited, let me state what I understand from your comment. Basically, you're saying that this problem cannot be solved algorithmically?

Comment: Also, the purpose of this exercise is not to visit all the airports.  These are the limitations    *the route network of Air India *flight timings *availability of flights on each day of week *the duration of the pass - 15 days *number of hours in a day - 24.   Given these limitations, what is the **maximum** number of airports that can be visited from a pre-defined departure point?

Comment: @Scubed: I say there is no **known** *polynomial* algorithm that solves this problem. You can try a [brute-force solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) which will take a very long time [probably decades and more], if you want an optimal solution. **Mathematical side note**: When I say "there is no known" - it is because our [humanity] understanding of computing is still limited, and we didn't manage to prove yet if there is or is not a polynomial algorithm for these problems. The general assumption is there isn't, but it is not proven,

Comment: @Scubed: Visiting the most possible number of airports is the optimization problem for visiting all airports problem, these two problems are identical - in terms of theoretical complexity.

Comment: @amit - that makes sense that are no known algorithms right now to solve this and brute force will be required. Do you know if there are any heuristic-based methods to solve this?

Comment: @Scubed: Not one that I am aware of - but I assume there are heuristics for it, I am not an expert on the field of heuristical/approximation algorithms.

Comment: There's no reason that a brute force approach should be nearly as slow as you suggest - the number of airports and flights are fairly limited.

Comment: @NickJohnson: trivial brute-force will have factorial behavior.. assuming we have ~50 airports, calculating 50! possibilities will take longer time then earth has to exist. I assume there are dynamic-programming based solution [such as for TSP], which can get this down to ~decade [assuming `O(n^2 * 2^n)`, such as TSP].

Comment: @amit Nobody said trivial, and the graph is undoubtedly not fully connected. TSPs with thousands of cities were solvable decades ago, on hardware available then.

Answer (score 1):

Representing your problem as a graph is definitely the best option. Since the duration, number of flights, and number of airports are relatively limited, and since you are (presumably) happy with approximate solutions, attacking this by brute force ought to be practical, and is probably your best option. Here's roughly what I would do:

- Represent each airport as a node on the graph, and each flight as an edge.
- Given a starting airport and a current time, select all the flights leaving that airport after the current time. Use a scoring function of some sort to rank them, such that flights to airports you haven't visited are ranked higher than flights to airports you haven't visited, and flights are ranked higher the sooner they are.
- Recursively explore each outgoing edge, in order of score, and repeat the procedure for the arriving airport.
- Any time you reach a node with no outgoing valid edges, compare it to the best possible solution. If it's an improvement, output it and set it as the new best solution.

Depending on the number of flights, you may be able to run this procedure exhaustively. The number of solutions grows exponentially with the number of flights, of course, so this will quickly become impractical. This is where the scoring function becomes useful - it prioritizes the solutions more likely to produce useful answers. You can run the procedure for as long as you want, and stop when it produces a solution you're happy with.

The properties of the scoring function will have a big impact on how good the solutions are. If your priority is exploring unique places, you want to put a big premium on unvisited airports, and since you want to explore as many as possible, you need to prioritize short transfer times. My suggestion for a starting point would be to make the penalty for going somewhere you've already been proportional to the time it would take to fly from there to somewhere else. That way, it'll still be explored as a stopover, but avoided where possible. Also, note that your scoring function will need context, namely the set of airports that have been visited by the current candidate path.

You can also use the scoring function to apply other constraints. Say you don't want to travel during the night (a reasonable assumption); you can penalize the score of edges that involve nighttime flights.

Comment: thanks @Nick Johnson, what you've recommended sounds like a good approach. Are there any python libraries or programs you would recommend that I look at for implementing this approach? I know only of [GUESS](http://graphexploration.cond.org/) and [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) and I'm not sure if these are the programs to use? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Scubed You shouldn't need any libraries - all of this can be implemented straightforwardly in pure Python, and doing so is probably a good exercise.